# how to override findElements() implementation in selenium with moveTo() each element using java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am using selenium webDriver with Java and looking for a solution to **find elements by moving to each element in the List at the time of selenium locating it**. A solution I am looking for specific to 'ChromeDriver', as chrome driver works with point/coordinates, each time my script failed to execute drag and drop list of elements identified from one location to another.

Scenario description: My application is having two tables (T1 and T2) with the list of 'li and ui' as subitems under each table row. I need to drag and drop 'T2' row/rows 'web elements' to matching web element under 'T1' row(same may be visible or not visible in the viewport during drag and drop- But I have used moveTo() method).

Issue: When I am executing the scripts in Chrome, web elements not present in the current viewport of 'T2' are clicked and dragged to matching 'parent web element' in 'T1'. But after the first run, web page alignment breaks and subsequent drag and drops are failing due to 'previously' identified elements position changed.

I have tried multiple approaches like, click the 'T2 element 1 and move and perform drag and drop, Using javascript executor display the element in viewport etc.. but each time the UI alignment breaks.

I would like to know that if anyone has worked on the custom implementation of 'Selenium FindElements() method with a MoveTo() function'?

> something like:

```
@Override
        public List<WebElement> findElements(By arg0) {
            List<WebElement> moveAndFind = null;
            try{
                WebElement firstIndex = Driver.findElement();//Move to first matching element of By argument.
                moveAndFind.add(firstIndex); // Collect all the matching elements in the web page by capturing the updated location - specific to Chrome driver
            }catch(WebDriverException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return moveAndFind;
        }
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to handle Chrome UI alignment breaks when Drag and drop operation performed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer specifically to your question, you cannot `override` the implementation of `FindElement` (or, since I'm not that familiar with the Java implementation, I'm not aware of something).

Now, to overcome your issue, you have several options:

1. Since you already have your list created, you could always move from the end of the list. This way, the order of elements is always the same with the initial index.
2. Use lambda expressions to identify the elements in your list by anything else but index.
3. Refresh and reconstruct your list after every move of an element. Depending you how many elements you need to move, this may prove to be the worse option performance wise.

Comment: Warm welcome for your key points!
But I have a large number of list items in each list. So reconstructing the list won't be a feasible solution as it will be a performance drain for in automation.

Comment: I thought so. Then the easiest options I see are to use drag and drop from the bottom of the list.